# Why is the letter 'Ñ' not recognised?

Tags: c#, console-application

I wrote a hangman game as a Windows console application.

When the user enters a character, the program checks if that character is a valid letter. If it is not, prints a message and ask for input again.

I added the letter 'Ñ' to the alphabet for words in Spanish, but it does not work. Here an example of the execution:

```
_______
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ
> E

E______
ABCD FGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ
> ,
Enter a valid letter
> A

E______
 BCD FGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ
> Ñ
Enter a valid letter
>
```

This is the alphabet:

```
char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
```

And this is how characters are validated:

```
char letter;
bool isValidLetter;
do
{
    Write("> ");
    isValidLetter = char.TryParse(ReadLine(), out letter);
    letter = char.ToUpper(letter);
    if (!isValidLetter || !alphabet.Contains(letter))
        WriteLine("Enter a valid letter");
} while (!isValidLetter || !alphabet.Contains(letter));
```

However, I think this is because of the encoding or something, right? Is there a way I can solve it?

Comment: Read the `char.TryParse()` docs: _"The conversion fails if the s parameter is null or the length of s is not 1"_.

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. How are you inputting the letter `Ñ`? What is the value of `letter` when you debug? Also, have you considered `Console.ReadKey()` instead?

Comment: When I copy and paste `Ñ` from your code and into the console app your code works fine. Your problem is that you're typing in a different character than `Ñ`.

Comment: @RufusL I forget Console.ReadKey could be useful for this, even though I did use it in other parts of the code. Now the game works fine with it, thank you!